# No such module 'AppInvokeSDK'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, paytm

**Paytm All-in-one SDK**  integrated successfully and working fine in simulator but when I am trying to run in real device, its giving me an error that **No such module 'AppInvokeSDK'**

**Cannot run in real device (iPhone 8)**

Following error getting in log:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppInvokeSDK.framework/AppInvokeSDK
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/840EAA6B-AB7E-4712-B77F-B6E625E899D2/app.app/app
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does your `AppInvokeSDK` include both device and simulator support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know later, By mistake I put framework in somewhere else. Actual place for external framework is inside the "**Framework**" folder in Xcode.

[image]